# Spiral hair on endpoint of the curve (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

I'm trying to create this effect on the hair, but all tutorial I found was about curly or spiral on the curve line. I even tried the "Roll hair Curve" ready preset, but I didn't get good results.
[image]

How can I achieve this roll on the endpoint of the hair?